# Discord bot not sending messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, javahelp

I am a beginner to using discord.js and cannot figure out why my bot isn't replying with a message whenever I send one on the server it's on. Discord says it's online and "Logged in!" comes up in the console when I run it, so client.on("ready") is working, but for some reason client.on("message") isn't. I was wondering if anyone could help me troubleshoot this, I've looked up multiple tutorials and everything looks right to me despite not working. Here is my code below:

```
const { Client, Intents} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const Wordle = require("./wordle.js");

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('The bot is online');
});

client.on('messageCreate', async msg =>
{
    //check for permission to post
    permision = msg.channel.permissionsFor(client.user);
    permision = permision.toArray();

    //dont respond to own messages
    if(msg.author.username === client.user.username) {return;}

    //loads a new wordle game
    if(msg.content.includes("!playwordle"))
    {
        Wordle.LoadNewWordle(msg);
    }
    //makes a guess in a wordle game
    if(msg.content.includes("!guess"))
    {
        Wordle.PlayWordle(msg);
    }
    //shows your stats
    if(msg.content.includes("!wordlestats"))
    {
        Wordle.ShowWordleStats(msg);
    }
});

client.login('xxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT checkbox checked in the discord developer portal?

Since August 31, 2022 access to message content became a Privileged Intent—like presence and guild member data.

If you don't have this checkbox checked you can find it in the portal https://discord.com/developers/applications > select your application > Bot > MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT

Source: https://autocode.com/discord/threads/what-are-discord-privileged-intents-and-how-do-i-enable-them-tutorial-0c3f9977/

That might solve your issue

Comment: yes I filled the checkboxes